# Change compileSdkVersion From 23 to 21

Tags: android, sdk

I want to change my compileSdkVersion from 23 to 21.

My problem is that I do not know, how should I do it and I take the following error :

Please guide me.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's happen because if you downgrade your compileSdkVersion you need to downgrade your support library version too, so every version of your support libraries should be 21.0.3 (max version for API 21) instead of 23.3.0

Comment: @MatPag Thanks for your reply.I change libraries from 23.3.0 to 21.0.3 but I take this error : Install Repository and sync project Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog.                                                                                        Basically what I should do? thanks

Comment: i've added an answer to help you better

Comment: @MatPag Thank you very much

Comment: If you solved your problem with my answer you can accept it and help others find the information usefull. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I take this error :                    Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:21.0.3
Install Repository and sync project                                                                                  Show in File                                                                                                      Show in Project Structure dialog.                                                                                                      Basically what I should do ? thanks

Comment: Install Repository and sync Project

Answer (score 0):

compileSdkVersion and support libraries version should have always the same major version value.

If you downgrade `compileSdkVersion` to API 21 you should downgrade your support libraries version to 21.0.3.

if you have: "Install Repository and sync project" error, you should upgrade the *Android Support Repository* from Android Studio following the official guide [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#download) as the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change some lines as following:

```
 compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.3"

compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:suppoert-v4:21.0.3'
```

if still red lines appears & showing error, then you need to install appropriate repositories or build tools.